# Which way of asking this question is correct?

Tags: sentence-construction

Does anyone know why hasn't the homework been released yet? vs Does anyone know why the homework hasn't been released yet?

Comment: It's quite unusual to hear of homework being *released*. Do you mean *assigned* or something else?

Comment: Yea it's an online thing we have to wait until they release it on a website... But which order is more correct?

Answer (score 1):

Note that comments under the question clarified that homework in this case os actually *released*, and not *assigned*, because it relates to an online course where it's made available.

---

There are two common variations of the sentence:

- ✔ Why hasn't the homework been released yet?
- ✔ Does anyone know why the homework hasn't been released yet?

The first can have more of a commanding tone (where an answer is demanded), while the second could be considered more polite. However, both are idiomatic and normal. Which to use is up to context and personal choice.

---

The first sentence in the question is not ordered in a conventionally normal or appropriate way:

- ✘ Does anyone know why hasn't the homework been released yet?

Note that it combines the wording, and word order, of the two variations above. One of those accepted variations should be used, but not this hybrid.